# What statistical methods would be recommended

Tags: descriptive-statistics

What types of statistical analysis should I use to questions like:

**1st question**: 
Have you had problems standing for longer than 30 min? 
possible answers: no problems - had to adjust to be able - impossible for me.

**2nd question**:
Do you have pain right now:  yes/no? Have you had pain since last meal: yes/no?

Have you performed any activities since last meal, how many times? _____________
(Last question has open answer where you should answer with f. eks 2.

Comment: What is the objective and context?

Comment: these are only examples of questions from an original questionnaire. The objective is to see if there is any correlation and I was thinking maybe logistic regression. I also want to use descriptive statistics.  what is your thoughts?

Comment: I agree with the comment by @user2974951.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do it's not possible to answer. Please edit your question with your goals, research questions, hypotheses or whatever.

Comment: The purpose of the study is too basically describe the data in the  first place. (Descriptive statistics)

Comment: For the second. It is a goal to see if there is any relationship between the ordered categorical variables and the binary variables. in context, relationship between physical activity and symptoms of disease.

Comment: @Jørn Tore: You didn't tell us things like number of respondents, questions about symptoms/sickness, ...  Can you please add this (and other extra information in comments) as an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three variables you describe are, in order, an ordered categorical variable, a binary categorical variable, and a count. If you were thinking of logistic regression then that is fine for the biary one. For the ordered categorical you need an ordinal regression model and for the third a Poisson regression.

For descriptives you might consider frequency tables or proportions for the first and second and the median with inter-quartile range for the third.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful :) I am trying to understand what types of analysis I can run with the data I am collecting. It is about Fibromyalgia patients and symptoms, where main goal is to look at symptomfluctuation that is binary variables and f. ex physical activities that is categorical  variables and the amount of physical activity that is numerical. 
Do you have some more good tips?